# How to write a RegExp which will get the text of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, regex

Each of my lists elements have attribute eg.: `data-content="1 000 PLN"`.

I want to write a RegExp query which will match this `data-content` doesn't matter if user write `1 000` or `1000`, `25 000 000` or `25000000` ?

I want to use this on JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regex, just use the [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]");
```

This will give you list of elements which have data-content attribute.

Then you can iterate the elements to get the attribute value

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]"), function( divChild ){
  console.log(divChild.getAttribute("data-content"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's not exacly what I want to obtain.

I have an `input` where user can white text. And I want to filter only this list elements which `data-content` is matched by query, but no matter if user write numbers with space.

Comment: @SzymonPajka You can append this HTML to a hidden element in body and run query selector on it, and finally remove this hidden element

Comment: Oh.. I'm not sure.

eg: I have 3 list elements with `data-content` values: `1 000 PLN`, `10 000 PLN` and `100 000 PLN`

and if user write: `100` I want to match all, but if he white `1 ` then I want to match only `1 000 PLN`.

and when I'm using `match` I mean I want to hidden rest of.

Comment: @SzymonPajka You can put all these filters on the returned element list.

Comment: Ok, I've got a solution. Like a comparing strings, mostly peoples are doing this using lowercase. Same pattern was to use here. Just compare this always without spaces :)

thanks for all response :)